# Retrofit 2 on sdk < 21

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, retrofit2.6

I used [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) library in my android application. My project's **minSDK** is 16. Now I see that my apps not working on SDK < 21 because of retrofit version. My retrofit version:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.1'
```

I tested **OkHttp 2** but it is not adapted with my retrofit. What should I do?

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: failed to connect to (my url) (port 443) after 10000ms

Comment: Please post the full stack trace from logcat.

Comment: Just this line printed in logcat.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that OkHttp3, from version 3.13.0 upped its minimum SDK version to API 21+.

If you just want to do basic HTTP(s) requests and do not care about TLS 1.2, then you can just exclude that specific version and use 3.12.13 which is the last version to support minSDK 9+.

```
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0") {
    exclude group: "com.squareup.okhttp3"
}

implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.13"
```

Add this to your build.gradle file and things should start working. However, from the next version, you should ideally be removing this and up your minSDK level to 21+.

Comment: Any one try this answer ?

Comment: @Plugie That did not work. still getting min SDK exception on okhttp3

Answer (score -1):

Add these lines in build gradle file:

```
    // retrofit, gson
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

This is complete package of retrofit